# SQL ISNUMERIC is returning odd results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

So I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM PE_ProductInstance WHERE ISNUMERIC(SerialStart) = 1) p
where 
    CAST(SerialStart AS int) < 8174
```

The subquery SHOULD, in theory, filter out any results where the column `SerialStart` is not numeric.  And indeed, when I look at the results of just:

```
 SELECT * FROM PE_ProductInstance WHERE ISNUMERIC(SerialStart) = 1
```

All of the results are indeed numeric for column `SerialStart`.  So I don't understand why that query results in this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '8A0357' to data type int.

Also what's weird is this query returns nothing:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM PE_ProductInstance WHERE ISNUMERIC(SerialStart) = 1) p
where 
    SerialStart  = '8A0357'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: 8A0357 is not a numeric and you are doing CAST(SerialStart AS int) < 8174

Comment: Read this article. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/why-doesn%E2%80%99t-isnumeric-work-correctly-sql-spackle

Comment: @Hasan I understand that. But why doesn't the sub-query filter out '8A0357'?

Comment: Don't not use `ISNUMERIC`, use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`. But if `SerialStart` **is** a number, why are you passing `8A9357`? That isn't a number. Perhaps you mean to reverse the logic, and should be ` = 0` (or rather, the `TRY_CONVERT` returns `NULL`)

Comment: The filter on `ISNUMERIC` can happen after the `CAST` anyway despite your use of a sub query. And this is what is happening here. `ISNUMERIC('8A0357')` returns `0` but the `CAST` runs on it anyway.

Comment: Use try_cast instead of a derived table.

Comment: I'm not sure if Itzik Ben-Gan once call this a bug, a feature or a creature.

T-SQL is partially a declarative language. This means that you're not telling it exactly what needs to be done and the engine will find the optimal way to do it.

The engine is actually creating a plan and filtering by `CAST(SerialStart AS int) < 8174` before getting to the `ISNUMERIC` comparison.

Comment: use `TRY_CAST`/`TRY_CONVERT` as the comments above already state, Then it doesn't raise an error if given invalid input

Comment: @LuisCazares, thank you! How do I make it do it the way I would expect?  I'm playing around with the other suggestions, but so for not getting it.  They all have the same problem, as you described.

Comment: I suggest that you use TRY_CONVERT or TRY_CAST and avoid this problem.

Comment: I'm struggling with the syntax of a TRY_CAST in a WHERE clause

Comment: there's nothing special about using it in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Basically, the easy solution is the one posted, but the reason of having the problem is not the same as the one on the "duplicate" question. The root cause is different and can cause other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try_Cast is the right method to do this. See this code:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE( 
    id int identity(1,1),
    name varchar(100));

INSERT into @table
VALUES
('1111'),('8A0357');

SELECT *
FROM @table p
WHERE TRY_CAST(p.Name AS int) < 8174;
```

Comment: you should just remove the whole `ISNUMERIC` check as `try_CAST(p.Name AS int) < 8174` will only return values successfully cast to int

Comment: AH!  I was trying to put the Try_Cast in the sub query